# Storing a float from user input in a char array and a float at once

Tags: c, arrays, input, floating-point

I was wondering if it is possible to receive **input** from the user and store copies of it in two variables of different types. Specifically, what I am trying to do is receive a **float** as an input and store it in a **char array** and also a **float** variable, so that I could use the **float** for computations and the **char array** to loop through the contents. I want to do this by asking the user to input his float number only once. Can I do this using `scanf()`? Thanks!

Comment: BTW, don't use `scanf()`, it's horrible and evil. Use sane functions, such as `fgets()` and `strtod()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Read in as string.  Save a copy as a string and scan the buffer for a `float`.

```
char buffer[100];
puts("input float number ");
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
char *x_as_string = strdup(buffer);

// Use sscanf()
float x_as_float;
if (1 != sscanf(buffer, "%f", &x_as_float)) Handle_ScanError();

//  or strtof() 
char *endptr;
errno = 0;
float x_as_float = strtof(buffer, &endptr);
if (endptr == buffer || *endptr != '\n' || errno) Handle_Error();
```